# polygon around polyline with radius?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, mapbox

I have the problem with drawing polygon around polyline.
I have coordinates of every polyline's point and I want to get coordinates of polygon around this polyline.
I use MapBox's map.
Any ideas? I didn't find solutions.
Something, that seems like this.
I need to get coordinates for drawing polygon around line.

[image]

Comment: What do you meant by **polygon around polyline**?? Sry cant get you.

Comment: Do you mean "outdent" instead of "indent"? To "indent" is to move inwards, you sound like you want to move outwards. How do you handle the ends? Should they be square, round, angled? Maybe also a drawing to illustrate and some code you already have or have tried.

Comment: Also, what classes are you using: [UIBezierPath](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath), [GMSPolyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_polyline), [GMSPolygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_polygon), [MGLPolylineFeature](https://mapbox.github.io/mapbox-gl-native/macos/0.5.0/Content%20Primitives.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLPolylineFeature)? What's your eventual use for the polygon?

Comment: i use MGLPolyline & MGLPolygon.
it could be squares, i just want to find simple solution.

Comment: I had a similar requirement and haven't found a good solution yet. I wanted to define a set of adjacent rectangles that covered a path so that I could download the appropriate offline Mapbox tiles for navigation when phone signal is absent. I ended up drawing the path in GoogleEarth and then dragging out a series of rectangles and copying across the coordinates. Works but is labour intensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution, guys! That was really diffucult :D 
According to last hint about Turf :)

**I found pod "SwiftTurf"**

```
var coordsPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CLLocationCoordinate2D>.allocate(capacity: Int(polyline.pointCount))
    polyline.getCoordinates(coordsPointer, range: NSMakeRange(0, Int(polyline.pointCount)))

    // save coords
    var lineCoords: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = []
    for i in 0..<polyline.pointCount {
        lineCoords.append(coordsPointer[Int(i)])
    }

    let lineString:LineString = LineString(geometry: lineCoords)

    let bufferLineString = SwiftTurf.buffer(lineString, distance: width, units: .Meters)

    let outer = bufferLineString!.geometry![0]
    let interiors = bufferLineString?.geometry![1..<bufferLineString!.geometry.count].map({ coords in
        return MGLPolygon(coordinates: coords, count: UInt(coords.count))
    })
    // This polygon is solution
    self.currentBufferPolygon = MGLPolygon(coordinates: outer, count: UInt(outer.count), interiorPolygons: interiors)
    mapView.addAnnotation(self.currentBufferPolygon!)
```

U can find more info on github in the pod's repo :) Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to draw a polygon around a polyline in the browser, I suggest using turf.js. Turf's [`buffer` method](http://turfjs.org/docs/#buffer) should work nicely for this exact case.

Here's an example on a Mapbox GL JS map

```js
var line = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [-122.40447521209718,
        37.79367718768535
      ],
      [-122.40803718566895,
        37.79171022624846
      ],
      [-122.40769386291502,
        37.79096412372944
      ],
      [-122.40662097930908,
        37.789641468930114
      ],
      [-122.40941047668457,
        37.789675383451495
      ],
      [-122.40992546081543,
        37.78875968591083
      ],
      [-122.40962505340575,
        37.78791180770003
      ]
    ]
  }
};

mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwc2FtIiwiYSI6ImNqNzI4ODR4djBkZmczMnJzZjg3eXZhcDgifQ.5xM2OR_RvuO6YvirBVeiOg';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
  zoom: 15,
  center: [-122.4067, 37.7899]
});

map.on('load', function() {
  map.addLayer({
    "id": "route",
    "type": "line",
    "source": {
      "type": "geojson",
      "data": line
    }
  });

  var polygon = turf.buffer(line, 50, 'meters');

  map.addLayer({
    "id": "poly",
    "type": "fill",
    "source": {
      "type": "geojson",
      "data": polygon
    },
    "layout": {},
    "paint": {
      "fill-color": '#d9d838',
      "fill-opacity": 0.3
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8' />
  <title></title>
  <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
  <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.39.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
  <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.39.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

  <script src='https://npmcdn.com/@turf/turf/turf.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='map'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: wow, it looks like a solution, but how can i adapt it to Swift?